# Two Navigation Controllers (in Storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6

So I am new to Objective C/iOS and so on... and I want to make something really simple. I want to have a Login view, and once that is done, I reach the "Main" of my application [HomePage in the image]. In that Home Page, I want to have a "brand new" Navigation controller, and the Home Page to be the root.

Now, if I want to Segue from the Login to Home, I have to have a Navigation controller at the left of the Login Controller. If I do that, the Home page will have a back button to the login screen and I don't want that. I want to delete that Login View if possible. I won't need it anymore unless the users clicks "Logout".

Basically two steps in my question:
[image]
1) How do I set the Navigation Controller for a new stream of View Controllers/View and delete the old set that is now unreachable.

2) Since there are no .xib files (because of Storyboard), how can I change between the views ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have to have a `Navigation Controller` on before `Login ViewController`. You could do it as following:

```
Login ViewController
    |
    |  (segue type = modal)
    | 
   \|/
Navigation Controller
    Main ViewController
```

Comment: Perfect got it! And do I need to worry about the Login VC not being deleted in memory?!

Comment: I don't think so if you are using storyboard

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue regarding on which to segue my log in. So does this mean I have to connect the login view to my navigation controller and not the main view controller? It's giving me a "Scene is unreachable.." warning on the login view and a "Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier to use with -[UIViewController performSequeWith....]" warning on the segue

Comment: @gdubs Yes, you need to connect your `Login VC` to `Nav Controller`

Comment: hi, but what if you're using jsonkit instead of json-framework?

Comment: @gdubs you should ask a new question describing what you have done and what you are trying to do.